# Ability to load component while axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

Is it possible to do the following: There is a `spinner` component.

**axios**:

```js
    method() {
     SPINNER (component) -- on
     axios.get('/shop', {
       params: {
         something
        }
      }) .then ((resp) => {
        SPINNER (component) -- off
      })
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is a very common way of displaying 'loading' spinners. What is your specific problem with this code?

Comment: @match thanks for the answer. Is there any example? I don’t know how to cast a component in axios so that it works as needed

Comment: Do you have a particular spinner component in mind? Some are controlled 'directly' via a prop, others expect you to enable/disbale them with v-if

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-if`:

```js
Vue.component('spinner', {
  template: `
    <div class="">
      loading...
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadData() {
    // this would be your axios call
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('finished loading!');
        // on success just change data property
        this.loading = false
      }, 2000);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadData()
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-if="!loading">loaded</div>
  <spinner v-if="loading" />
</div>
```